# Redux update additional props in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which is using redux connect. In this component I have **mapStateToProps** which getting project from redux state and projectTransform is a value which has filter values from project redux state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ProjectForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { 
      fetchProject, 
    } = this.props;

    fetchProject();

  }
  onClick() {
    this.setState({
      project1: {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
      }
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { project1 } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick()} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ProjectForm.propTypes = {
  fetchProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return 
    fetchProject: () => dispatch(projectActions.getProjectRequest()),
  }
}

function mapStateToProps ( state ) {
  const { project} = state
  return {
    project: project,
    project1: ((project) => {
      return project[0]
    })(project)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectForm)
```

I trying to now trigger re-rendering on the button but I have not clue how to do it as I tried.

```
this.setState((previousState) => {
 project1: [JSON value from Form]
});
```

Also why previousState is null I would assume it would have mapStateToProps data. 
Any idea how to do it without dispatching whole redux? Or how to do it in a proper way?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more information. What button are you referring to? I don't see any code for it, or the function it invokes onClick. What component are you trying to setState in? Does it have a project1 state and prop? What is the purpose of the project1 method inside the mapStateToProps? The project1 method seems unnecessary. Your `setState` updater method doesn't return anything, nor do you seem to use `prevState` anywhere.

Comment: Hi I have a button in render method and on clicking it doing setState. I don't want to do forceUpdate

Comment: You never set your initial state, so the first update would have a prevState of null. You also need to change `<button onClick={onClick()} />` to `<button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />`. You are trying to invoke the onClick method inside the assignment. You're also referencing it incorrectly. You will also need to bind `this` context of your onClick callback method. I recommend doing this in the constructor of your class, not inline as shown above for brevity. Inline function binding in the render method of a component will break PureComponents and force unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: If this fixes you mentioned will fix issue with set state not trigger render. I don't think so. Code was a little bit boillaple to show concept what Im trying to do

Comment: 100%, `<button onClick={onClick()} />`, is not how you reference a callback method for a react `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with reading data not from the state but props.

```
render() {
    const { project1 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick()} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```